# How to go from $5\pi/4$ to $\pi + \pi/4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Use standard triangles to find exact value of $\cos(5\pi/4)$.

Example states that $5\pi/4$ is equal to $\pi + \pi/4$ but doesn't list the steps to get $\pi + \pi/4$...

Comment: $\frac{5\pi}{4}=\frac{4\pi+\pi}{4}=\frac{4\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}=\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$. Or go the other way, bring $\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$ to a common denominator $4$. Or notice that $5$ quarters (coins) is $1$ dollar plus a quarter.

Comment: Not to be rude, but you really should consider going over algebra basics before moving on to trigonometry. From experience teaching students that have miraculously made it to calculus without internalizing fractions, it doesn't end well.

Answer (score 4):

Hint, what if you write:

$$\pi = (4 \pi )/4$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $\frac54=\frac{4+1}4=\frac44+\frac14.$ Distribute the $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks all. I spoke to my lecturer today who said to look at it like a pie, literally. So we have a whole pie plus a quarter ie Pi + Pi/4. Which made it a lot easier to understand, although I can grasp the concepts you have given.

Comment: Absolutely an excellent way to think about fractions, in general (not just fractions of $\pi$).

Answer (score 2):

$\pi$ is just like any other number. So you can do $\frac{5 \pi}{4} = \frac{4 \pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{4} = \pi + \frac{\pi}{4}$ just like you can do $\frac{5}{4} = \frac{4}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = 1 + \frac{1}{4}$.